# Mix colour in Sprite Kit

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I am new to Sprite Kit and I want to use it implement a simple game. I'd like to know if this is possible in Sprite Kit:

Assume I draw two circles, one in **Red** and the other one in **Green**. There is a overlap area between this two circles and I want the colour of this area can be automatically set to **RED + Green = Yellow**, kind of like the picture below.

Is it possible to do so using Sprite Kit? If it is possible, how to set it up?

Any reply is greatly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can play with a [blending mode](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKSpriteNode_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKSpriteNode/blendMode) in conjunction with [SKEffectNode](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKEffectNode_Ref/index.html):

```
class GameScene:SKScene{

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {


        let effect = SKEffectNode()

        //Creating shapenodes
        let shape1 = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 50)
        shape1.fillColor = SKColor.redColor()
        shape1.strokeColor = SKColor.clearColor()
        shape1.zPosition = 1
        shape1.blendMode = SKBlendMode.Add

        let shape2 = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 50)
        shape2.fillColor = SKColor.greenColor()
        shape2.strokeColor = SKColor.clearColor()
        shape2.zPosition = 2
        shape2.blendMode = SKBlendMode.Add

        let shape3 = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 50)
        shape3.fillColor = SKColor.blueColor()
        shape3.strokeColor = SKColor.clearColor()
        shape3.zPosition = 3
        shape3.blendMode = SKBlendMode.Add


        //Positioning
        shape1.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(frame))

        shape2.position = CGPoint(x: shape1.position.x - 25, y: shape1.position.y - 50)

        shape3.position = CGPoint(x: shape1.position.x + 25, y: shape1.position.y - 50)

        effect.addChild(shape1)
        effect.addChild(shape2)
        effect.addChild(shape3)

        self.addChild(effect)

    }
}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I want! Thanks!

Comment: One more question. Instead of filling the circle with solid colour, if I filled it with a coloured texture (such as png pictures with Red and Green patterns), is there anyway to reach a similar effect?

Comment: @HunTerDRF Yeah, you could use SKSpriteNode and initialize it with a texture.

Comment: Thanks! I will give it a try!